# Using the firefox-addon SDK panel module without the boxed look

Tags: css, sdk, firefox-addon, panel, mozilla

I would like to use the panel module (i.e. attach not only script but also html and CSS and not have the addon CSS and JavaScript potentially interact with that of the main page) but not have the restraints of the boxed look.  It seems like this ought to be fairly simple, but the only way I see to do this is to use the low lying APIs which lack much of the simplicity, security and documentation of the high level apis.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the following:

- [Stylesheet Service](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_the_Stylesheet_Service)
- [UserChrome.css](http://kb.mozillazine.org/index.php?title=UserChrome.css)
- [UserChrome.js](http://kb.mozillazine.org/index.php?title=UserChrome.js)

  - [UserChrome.js Extension](http://userchromejs.mozdev.org/)
- [Resource Aliases](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Chrome_Registration#resource)